# ¿Es posible restringir la visualización de datos para un usuario en MongoDB Compass?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, nosql, mongoatlas

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que utiliza MongoDB como base de datos y Mongodb Atlas,  MongoDB Compass como herramienta de administración. Quisiera saber si es posible aplicar restricciones en la visualización de datos para usuarios específicos en MongoDB Compass. Necesito asegurarme de que ciertos usuarios solo puedan ver datos autorizados y no tengan acceso a información restringida. ¿Existe alguna funcionalidad en MongoDB Compass que permita configurar este nivel de acceso y restricción de datos para usuarios individuales? Agradecería mucho cualquier orientación o ejemplos sobre cómo lograr esto de manera efectiva. ¡Gracias!

Comment: En Compass no, pero en Mongo Atlas podrías configurar [User Roles](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/user-roles/) para crear roles con diferentes niveles de acceso y así asignar usuarios a los roles específicos. Saludos

Comment: Adicionalmente puedes leer la documentación sobre [seguridad y usuarios](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-add-mongodb-users/) de Atlas.